# pass the position for an element in react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to set the position from of an element "from outside". But I get an error "unexpected keyword top".
What I basically try to achieve, is to create an element "Field". Then I want to initiate multiple Fields, with different positions. The Fields will be combined to a "game board" (e.g. for chess play)

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rectangle: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 99,
    top: {this.props.top},     // <--- this does not work
    left: '5%',
  },
});
```

Basically I just want to create a Field like this `<Feld x='10' y='10'/>`, then the Field should be shown at location x, y.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array of styles, so for example your view should be something like: <View style={[styles.rectangle, {top: this.props.top}]}/>, and remove the "top:{this.props.top}" from the rectangle style.